# Clean up pull request commits

Tags: git, pull-request

- I branched off (`my_branch`) from `master`.
- While working on `my_branch`, there were updates to `master`.
- I was regularly re-basing `my_branch` to then latest `master`.
- With one re-base later though there was a conflict. I remember resolving the conflict and `git rebase --continue`.
- For some reason, rebase steps I took didn't help, I ended up performing a merge of the new commits to `master`.
- Between my last successful rebase and the current merge, there were a few commits in the master. These commits now merged onto `my_branch`
- Now my pull request shows the changes from these commits that were merged.

Is there a way for me to clean up the pull request to show only the changes I made?

Also, is there a way for me to see in local what a pull request would look like for the reviewer? Is it just doing a diff between (1) the commit in `master` from where `my_branch` was created, and (2) the latest code I have in `my_branch`?

Comment: did you do local commit in my_branch before merging?

Comment: @MaraYes, I did merge, local commit, then pushed to remote.

Comment: Pull requests are (generally—there's a `git request-pull` command, but this is rather different from what most people think of here) handled by whichever web service you are using. Different web providers handle pull requests differently, so all of this depends on which web provider you are using. (If it's GitHub, well, what they show on a pull request is rather impenetrable unless it's a very simple pull request.)

Comment: I do usually one more step: 1. commit; 2. merge; 3. commit; 4. push. With such approach I have merged changes in separate commit and during push I can review all commits separately.